# How to re-direct logkeys to standard out?

Tags: linux

Logkeys does not support the `-o -` as standard output (it makes a file called `-`).  Any idea how to re-direct its output file to standard out?  This does not work either:

```
sudo logkeys -m colmak.us.map  -o /dev/stdout  -s
logkeys: Error opening output file '/dev/stdout': No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Research shows that `logkeys` does [funny stuff with `stdout`](https://mailman.archlinux.org/pipermail/arch-general/2012-January/023790.html). I think you need to make sure that your version is build with the [`stdout.patch`](http://ftp.free.org/pub/frugalware/frugalware-current/source/apps-extra/logkeys/logkeys-stdout.patch). Have you tried using normal redirects to capture the output?

Comment: Wow, nice find.  In all fairness, your answer is right on for my question as it is worded.  Although I would likely use the temporary file as that would not be specific to the version of logkeys.

Answer (score 2):

You could either create a temporary named pipe, or file, and cat that file, or tail -f the file,

Wrap your command,

```
sudo logkeys -m colmak.us.map  -o /dev/stdout  -s
```

In a shellscript, which examines the filename argument, and either uses the provided file, or builds a tempfile for stdout ("-" or "/dev/stdout"),

```
#!/bin/bash
tempfile="nil";
outfile=${1:-"-"};
#generate temporary filename
[[ $outfile == "/dev/stdout" ]] && outfile="-";
[[ $outfile == "-" ]] && outfile=`mktemp` && tempfile=$outfile;
[[ $1 ]] && sudo logkeys -m colmak.us.map  -o $tempfile  -s
[[ $tempfile != "nil" ]] && cat $tempfile && echo rm $tempfile
```

Echoing the commands, produces,

```
$ ./aliasout.sh /tmp/myfile
sudo logkeys -m colmak.us.map -o /tmp/myfile -s
$ ./aliasout.sh /dev/stdout
sudo logkeys -m colmak.us.map -o /tmp/tmp.ghTUwmOzdS -s
rm /tmp/tmp.ghTUwmOzdS
$ ./aliasout.sh -
sudo logkeys -m colmak.us.map -o /tmp/tmp.heRi4ntAM0 -s
rm /tmp/tmp.heRi4ntAM0
```

Comment: Looks like this will work for years to come.  I will probably simplify this down to a few lines and clean-up using a TRAP signal.  Thank you!